# Replacing date value in parameter file using Informatica post session command

Tags: unix, informatica

I have parameter $$RUN_DATE=21/12/2018 in a parameter file with yesterday's date. During run time, the Informatica session override will pull the data from Yesterday's run time to till the current time. After the run of Informatica session, the $$RUN_DATE has to get replaced in the parameter file. I have tried  below command

> sed -e 's,^($$RUN_DATE=).*,\1'"$(date +"%m%d%Y")"','

using post session command task, but during run time, the $$RUN_DATE is getting replaced with the value in the parameter file. Can I have solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the parameter file content?.. please elaborate with sample input and expected output

Comment: It has all the parameters like source connect, target connections and all other workflow parameters. I need the $$RUN_DATE parameters to be updated at the end of the session run every time.  I have the restriction that I need to use only param file.

Comment: just share the before and after snapshots of the param file,,

Comment: I'm trying below command to replace a date pattern, but it is throwing error. Sed -i 's/"12/18/2018"/$(today %m%d%Y)' file.txt

Answer (score 0):

There are few options here. You could have a session that reads the parameter file and sets the new values. I guess this would be more explicit.

If you want to use sed, you could either try to escape the `$` sign:

```
sed -e 's,^($$RUN_DATE=).*,\1'"$(date +"%m%d%Y")"','
```

This way Informatica should not replace it with the param value.

Or try to skip the `$` sign in regexp definition and do not hook up to the begining of the line:

```
sed -e 's,(RUN_DATE=).*,\1'"$(date +"%m%d%Y")"','
```

This however depends on the rest of your paramfile contents.